# Change color of console font for nodejs debug libary in Webstorm

Tags: node.js, webstorm

Is there a way to change the font color of logs inside the Webstorm editor?
I am using this https://github.com/visionmedia/debug library for logs. In my Linux terminal:

```
var debug_log = debug('test:log');
var debug_error = debug('test:error');
debug_log('log'); // displays in a different color than
debug_error('log');
```

In Webstorm they are both red.
Is it possible to change the color? The library says consoles that understands the `%c` option can display the logs in different colors. Is Webstorm able to be configured that way?

Answer (score 3):

This library requires TTY console for colored output. And Node.js run console in WebStorm is non-TTY, as node process is started with input/output streams redirection. Please see [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-1933).